# CF Entity Framework searching across compound entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Suppose I have three models in an entity framework using code-first, one is the primary which a 1-n relationship to the another and that has a 1-1 relationship to a third.

For example

```
public class Model {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string value {get; set;}

  // 1-N relationship to modelInfo
  public virtual ICollection<ModelInfo> modelInfo {get; set;}
}

public class ModelInfo {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string value2 {get; set;}

  // 1-1 relationship between modelInfo and modelDetail
  public virtual ModelDetail {get; set;}

  [Required]
  // link back to the model
  public virtual Model model;
}

public class ModelDetail {
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string modelDetail {get; set;}

  [Required]
  // 1-1 link back to the modelInfo
  public virtual ModelInfo modelInfo;
}
```

Now given that model, suppose you have a collection of models already, from a previous linq query.

```
IQueryable<Model> models;
```

and you need to find which Model is associated with a ModelDetail that has modelDetail = "findme" ? using linq syntax.. or is that even possible?

Something like

```
 ModelDetail foundit = models.Where( m => m..??.. modelDetail=="findme" );
```

I get lost in the 1-N relationship between Model and ModelInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ModelDetail`:

```
context.ModelDetails
       .Where(md => md.modelDetail == "findme")
       .Select(md => md.modelInfo.model)
```

Or from `ModelInfo`:

```
context.ModelInfos
       .Where(mi => mi.modelDetail.modelDetail == "findme")
       .Select(mi => mi.model);
```

Or from `Model`:

```
context.Models
       .Where(m => m.modelInfo
                    .Any(mi => mi.modelDetail.modelDetail == "findme"));
```

To return `ModelDetail` from `Model`:

```
context.Models
       .SelectMany(m => m.modelInfo)
       .Select(mi => mi.modelDetail)
       .Where(md => md.modelDetail == "findme");
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  Very close to what I am trying to do.  I like the third method, from Model (I actually am not exposing the sub-models directly from my context anyway, maybe a bad decision, but it seems right as that data can only exist as part of the main model).  That example finds a model with modelinfos, one of which has a modelDetail == findme. but It doesn't actually select the modelDetail.  It instead is returning a model..  At which point I'm still stuck with the problem of finding the specific modelDetail.